# puppetdb stores hash facts as string for some of my nodes

Tags: puppet

Some facts supposed to be hash are stored as string in puppetdb.

For example:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/v3/nodes/tcentos/facts/partitions
[ {
  "value" : "sda1uuid1b97126a-beb2-4843-8c7b-4e6e12cbfbb7mount/bootsize1024000filesystemext4sda2size40916992filesystemLVM2_member",
  "name" : "partitions",
  "certname" : "tcentos"
} ]
```

while it should be like this:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/v3/nodes/tfedora20/facts/partitions
[ {
  "value" : "{\"sda1\"=>{\"uuid\"=>\"8e6cda9b-54b7-4daa-a25c-1864a163f7a8\", \"size\"=>\"1024000\", \"mount\"=>\"/boot\", \"filesystem\"=>\"ext4\"}, \"sda2\"=>{\"size\"=>\"15751168\", \"filesystem\"=>\"LVM2_member\"}}",
  "name" : "partitions",
  "certname" : "tfedora20"
} ]
```

When I run `facter partitions` on `tcentos` node, the return value is OK.

```
[root@tcentos ~]# facter partitions
{"sda1"=>{"mount"=>"/boot", "filesystem"=>"ext4", "size"=>"1024000", "uuid"=>"1b97126a-beb2-4843-8c7b-4e6e12cbfbb7"}, "sda2"=>{"filesystem"=>"LVM2_member", "size"=>"40916992"}}
```

my Puppet Environment:

```
Puppet Master : 3.7.5
Puppet Agent  : 3.7.5
PuppetDB      : 2.3.0
```

The puppet agents and facter on all my nodes are exactly the same version. Does anybody have the same issue?

-----------------------Update---------------------

I got the reason with the help of @FelixFrank from the comments. This is about [stringify_facts configuration](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#stringifyfacts).

we can set `stringify_facts=false` in `puppet.conf` (main section on all agents and masters) to disable flattening fact values to strings. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/latest/fact_overview.html#writing-structured-facts), structured facts support is enabled by default from 3.7 and later. But I guess the default behaviour is different on Open Source Puppet, so we have to explicitly add this setting.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/v3/nodes/tcentos/facts/partitions
[ {
  "value" : "{\"sda1\":{\"filesystem\":\"ext4\",\"mount\":\"/boot\",\"size\":\"1024000\",\"uuid\":\"1b97126a-beb2-4843-8c7b-4e6e12cbfbb7\"},\"sda2\":{\"filesystem\":\"LVM2_member\",\"size\":\"40916992\"}}",
  "name" : "partitions",
  "certname" : "tcentos"
} ]
```

Although the result is still a string instead of actual JSON data, but it's way better than a key-value concatenation and I can parse it easily.

Comment: They both look funny. The first is a stringification through concatenation of keys and values, the other is a string containing JSON-ish data. Should the JSON you receive not contain an actual JSON hash instead of either string?

Comment: @FelixFrank Oh, you are right, I even didn't notice that. The second one is not quite normal because of the strange escape character. So actually they are both stored as (or presented as) string! But where can I find the reason? Those One-level key-value are presented as normal , the problem is the nested ones. The value in a key-value pair has to be a string in PuppetDB? Any ideas?

Comment: I vaguely remember something about Puppet still stringifying facts per default, even those that are structured. There is a Puppet agent setting for that I believe.

Comment: @FelixFrank You pointed me to the right direction. Yes, there is a setting for this, which is `stringify_facts`. I added `stringify_facts=false` in `puppet.conf` and it worked...At least not just a concatenation of keys and values. Thank you!!

Comment: FWIW, master configuration likely has no say in this.